# as3 move object back and forth on iPad or tablet

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on a 2d project for iPad where a ball moves back and forth. When it hits the border it has to rotate a bit and roll back in another direction and leaving a child behind that also starts to move and follows a random path. (I made the project in Scratch. See code.)

```
ball_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);

function moveBall(e:Event):void {

ball_mc.rotation += 1;
if (ball_mc.x < (stage.stageWidth - 100)) {
    //trace('move forward');
    ball_mc.x += 2;

} else {
    // while(ball_mc.x > 100)?
    //  trace('move backward');
    //  how does it roll back? 
        ball_mc.x += -2;
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable that holds the value of the direction or velocity. This variable should be changed to `2` if the ball passes a left side boundary and changed to `-2` if the ball passes a right side boundary. Like this:

```
var ballSpeed:Number = 0;   // this should go where you declare global variables such as at the beginning of your main class before the constructor



ball_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);

function moveBall(e:Event):void {

ball_mc.rotation += ballSpeed;
if (ball_mc.x < (stage.stageWidth - 100)) {
    ballSpeed = 2;   
} else if (ball_mc.x > stage.stageWidth){ 
    ballSpeed = -2;
}
```